# Assets loading slowly in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Each page request in my app pulls down about 30 assets (JavaScripts and images), which is both third-party stuff in vendors/ and app/ stuff. Of course, all the JavaScript is combined and minified in production, so it's fine there, but in development, it's really slow. Like 8 seconds to load the page and will only get worse. Is this normal and what can be done to speed it up?

I tried moving images from assets/ to public/, but it serves them just as slowly. About 3-4 files a second.

This is happening on a fast Macbook Pro with both WEBrick and Unicorn.

Comment: How many workers have you opened in unicorn? WEBrick can handler one request at a time so it's normal to take 8 seconds for 30 assets. If you configure unicorn with 4-5 workers it will load much faster

Comment: Good idea, but I've just tried this with 2, 5, and 16. No noticeable difference unfortunately. Just to be clear, I'm setting "worker_processes 5" in config/unicorn.rb and running bundle exec unicorn_rails.

Comment: Make sure to check with firebug or chrome developer tools to be sure what is taking the time - it may be the main page and not the assets. I've got nearly 20 assets and the time it takes is less than 1/2 a second (pages with little database work).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Turning off asset debugging should improve the speed a bit.

```
#development.rb
config.assets.debug = false
```

Comment: what is the drawback of doing that?

Comment: Downside is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20859448/18706 - source files are combined together and source maps won't work (e.g. if using Sass/Coffee you won't see it in devtools)

Comment: Switched this to the accepted answer as rails-dev-tweaks is unmaintained and doesn't do anything for Rails 4. This answer is quite effective for improving asset speed.

Comment: could you please tell me why asset load very slowly when it set = true? thank you

Comment: We were having extreme compile times on our sass for a rather large app and a combination of this answer and switching to sassc-rails gem vs sass-rails sped up our sass compiles 5x (ish)

Answer (score 9):

Most likely, the problem is that Rails reloads all classes on each assets request. This gem: https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks fixes the problem by tweaking Rails autoload rules.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of reloading. Didn't know that happens, I'll check out dev tweaks thanks.

Comment: @mahemoff If this solved the issue it should be marked as the answer.

Comment: this does not work at all in Rails 4.2. Not sure why. Moving to Thin in development brought some improvements

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) server. Was also slowing down my development environment(taking me +- 12 seconds). Add it do your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem "thin"
end
```

bundle and run with:

```
thin start
```

Before precompiling assets i brought my load time down to +-5 (with some configuration and code refactoring). Hope it helps

[image]

-source thin website

Comment: Thanks for the profiling data. Unfortunately it worked about as fast more me as unicorn. Takes 6 seconds to load about 30 files, which is what it takes until the app is runnable (those are mostly JS/CSS files).

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) and its associated plugins to precompile assets in the background as you edit them in the filesystem.

Comment: I may have to resort to this. I think it will be a lot of time to set it up in a way that still works properly with the asset pipeline in production.

Answer (score 0):

I believe rails has to compile the assets each time in development, whereas for production, it dosn't, apart from the first time this would lead to it being slow in development.