# Rails 5 Request ran for longer than 5000ms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm stumped.  I have a vanilla install of Rails 5 running within docker yet I'm constantly getting this error:

`Request ran for longer than 5000ms`

[image]

All I've done so far was generate a new controller with `docker-compose run website rails g controller pages`.

So far, if I remove (very important) lines from `layouts/application.html.erb`, I can get the page to load:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

But I loose all my default styling (bootstrap) and any potential javascript files I wish to load later in life, which I do not consider to be a fix.

Anyone else run into this problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: Try setting config.assets.debug to false in config/development.rb just to see if you can get the page to load.

Comment: Yup that works.... what ramifications does leaving it to false have?

Comment: I always set mine to false. When it's set to true, the assets that are required in the application manifest files will be served individually. So the stuff that's required in application.js is served using individual script tags.

Answer (score 1):

@JimmyBaker answered in the comments

> Try setting config.assets.debug to false

Inside `config/development.rb`

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

Having this set to false will cause all CSS & JS to be bundled into `application.css` or `application.js` [More on assets.debug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20859448/615397)