# javascript library's image asset not found in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, asset-pipeline

We use the [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) network library in our rails 5 app. It is installed via yarn and required in the asset pipeline (application.js):

```
//= require vis/dist/vis
//= require vis/dist/vis-network.min
```

Everything is fine in the development environment, but our capybara feature test raises an error

```
Rack app error handling request { GET /assets/img/network/editIcon.png }       
#<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/assets/img/network/editIcon.png">
```

The worst thing is that this error does not always appear, but the png is never visible on capybara screenshots.

Any clue, why development and test environment could differ here?

Answer (score 1):

Running `config.assets.debug = true` in test mode is not a great solution, since it means your test environment no longer matches your production environment from an assets perspective (no concatenation, etc).

The correct solution is to add the paths where the image assets are specified from to `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` (usually done in `config/initializers/assets.rb`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for myself after all. After adding `config.assets.debug = true` we got back the png. The effect of this option is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20859448/2459156